# Using existing ssh key in Terraform with Digitalocean provider

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I have deployed and configured some droplets with Terraform in DO with my ssh key e.g.,

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "bla" {

  name   = "blabla"
  size   = "s-2vcpu-4gb"
  image  = "debian-10-x64"
  region = "ams2"
  ipv6   = true
  ssh_keys = [
               data.digitalocean_ssh_key.mySshKey.id,
             ]
}
```

Our org has many ssh keys in DO and now I want to just say

```
  ssh_keys = [
               data.digitalocean_ssh_key.mySshKey.id,
               data.digitalocean_ssh_key.uncleBob.id,
             ]
```

And have both public keys in authorized_keys file. Simples. Obviously the key with name `uncleBob` exists in DO. Four days have gone. Anyone could kindly offer a recipe?

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource
Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
etc etc
```

To clarify - I do not ask about my configuration, I ask about a *standard* way to add ssh keys existing in DO to a new droplet via terraform:

- If I define the key in root.tf it is Error creating SSH Key ... SSH Key is already in use on your account.
- If I simply use the reference to that key on a droplet definition, it is Error: Reference to undeclared resource.

How am I to break this viscous circle?

Comment: And where is the data source defined in your code?

Comment: If you actually want help with this, show the full error message in your question including exact line numbers that it references, and show the full Terraform code. Nobody can help you with some tiny bit of an error message with no context and an "etc etc" as if we are supposed to know intuitively what the "etc" is.

Comment: @MarkB disagreed. Those who bumped into that before could.

Comment: @MarkoE Nowhere. It works like that from the outset with key `mySshKey` that is defined in DigitalOcean via GUI. So, I want the second one to only be defined there as well. there is `terraform import` documented in `digitalocean_ssh_key` docs, but it requires `ID` not being exposed by DO.

Comment: @wick you may disagree, but this website has a policy that questions should include debugging details, and enough information to reproduce the problem. Questions can be closed for not meeting those criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case wonderers stumble across this... We were looking for https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/data-sources/ssh_key